# Mysql Multiple Bulk Update

Tags: mysql, centos

I have issues with the time it takes MySQL to update multiple rows, see example below:

```
update sub set rn='Q',bdate=now() where id='43721';
update sub set rn='Q',bdate=now() where id='905666';
update sub set rn='Q',bdate=now() where id='356748';
update sub set rn='Q',bdate=now() where id='57848';
update sub set rn='Q',bdate=now() where id='25359';
update sub set rn='Q',bdate=now() where id='100060';
```

Can anyone suggest a faster way to do this?
I have 100,000 records to update in this format.

I update the records with the following command:

```
mysql -u root -pXxXX XXXXX -h xx.xx.xx.xx < /root/code/sub01.txt
```

Michael

Comment: You have no other criteria  for the rows to update other than a hard-coded list of IDs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE id IN (<list of ids>)` to do them all at once.

```
UPDATE sub 
SET rn = 'Q', bdate = NOW()
WHERE id IN (43721, 905666, 356748, ...)
```

Comment: You might want to use single quotes, though it would probably work either way, with the `id` column being either type +1.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and assuming he didn't really need the quotes.